# async method doesn't show up as async when reference by another project

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await

I have a method defined in a dll as this :

```
public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(PtiType clientType, PtiType communicationType,string serverIp,int portNum= 3200)
```

In different project, I reference to that dll and use 'await' keyword with it. And I got this error from Intellisense.
[image]

Having a look at Metadata of that reference, I see this

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public Task<bool> ConnectAsync(PtiType clientType, PtiType communicationType, string serverIp, int portNum = 3200);
```

What happened with my async keyword?

UPDATE:
I'm using .NET 4.5 for both projects.

Comment: What framework version are you targeting in the _other_ project (which references the assembly that should contain the `async` method)?

Comment: Does the calling assembly support async? Is it DotNet 4.5?

Comment: `async` doesn't need to be part of the metadata (part of "what you need to know to know how to call `ConnectAsync`"). It's really an implementation detail. While there are [good reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/11/11/whither-async.aspx) why you write it there in your own code, it doesn't need to be there in metadata.

Comment: Have you tried to search for error you are getting "The `await` operator can only be used within async method"? Or at least follow guidance give in the error message - "consider marking **this** method..."?

Comment: I'm sorry, I so focus into the thing in metadata and forgot that I met this error before.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov. I guess, the author of the question was just confused of 'async' word, as the callee does have it (when rather the caller must have it in this situation). For me (when I even really think MS done their job great) the async/await logic is still looks like a bit not a piece of cake (especially, for beginners). But that's rather the best what could have been done in this situation *(except more clear error message)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use **await**, your caller (not only called one (in your case)) method must be marked as async as well.

```
public async void YorCaller()
{
    var result = await ConnectAsync(...);
}
```

## updated:

As correctly mentioned in comments, the called method really don't have to be marked as 'async' (if it does not use any 'await' operation(s) inside) -- I was just mentioning "not only ... one" in reference to this very sample.

Comment: +1 you just beat me to the answer. I think likely it will be `async Task` though, not `async void`

Comment: If possible, use `async Task`, not `async void`, so that whoever calls `YorCaller()` has options besides "fire and forget".

Comment: In fact, the awaited method doesn't need to be marked as `async` at all.  It can be any method that returns a `Task` (or other awaitable object).  `async` is just one possible way of creating a method that returns an awaitable object.

Comment: You can use async Task<T> for sure as well, but there always must be some async void at the top of callers stack anyway.

Comment: @Agat No, actually, not necessarily.  Potentially, but not necessarily.

Comment: @Servy. Well, that can be async Task or async Task<T> of course, that usually just would not have any sense. As on the top is rather some event handler (void one) or some other similar functionality. I speak not from strict rules but just general logic (from my experience).

Comment: I have an await call in ConnectAsync. If I don't use await when calling Instance.ClientImplementation.ConnectAsync(...), the next line after calling ConnectAsync() is excuted without any blocking from ConnectAsync, right?

Comment: @LxL You really should try using await as much as it possible as await/async was intended to bring easier code reading.

Comment: @Agat There are constructs in which the top level function is itself designed for a task based asynchronous style of programming, and as such accepts a task, rather than being void.  While in some paradigms that isn't an option yet, or possibly even can't be, that's not *strictly* the case, merely *sometimes* the case.

Comment: @Servy. We are talking about different things. Read carefully my words. The toppest caller would rather always be 'void'. Because if you implement 'Task' or 'Task<T>' that means that we expect that method to be called as some 'instrument' or something. *(Just by definition (as if you return some value, it's suppose to be used by some other caller))*. And why I actually mention 'void on top', because it allows beginners to catch how should they use the await/async in some UI logic (for instance) (when some of your events handler loads certain data with using async callees).

Comment: @Agat Yes, and you say *always* and I'm saying that's not true.  It's a *sometimes*, even at the top level.  One can have a message loop that doesn't have fire and forget methods, but rather that is built around task returning methods; one could have a testing framework built around the TPL, or a parallelization framework in which the *top level* methods all return tasks.  Many UI frameworks, for the sake of backwards compatibility, can't do that, but even that can/will change over time.  `async void` methods are a hack, and one that is only *sometimes* needed.

Comment: @Servy. I possibly was a bit incorrect on the 4th comment (with mentioning "always" (there is no such rule or guidelines, for sure)), but I still mentioned "would rather always be" in the last my one. And, that's hard to talk with people which **always** see only certain point on the line and not any other possible ways another people (especially, beginners) can see some things which they bumping into first (incl., async/await) (and in which conditions they do that). So, we can just stop that discussion for The Greatest Computer Goddess to decide who is right and who is not. he he